# How are higher dimensional sphere packings used in signal transmission?

Tags: signal-processing, cellphone, signal-to-noise, signal-theory, internet

How are higher dimensional sphere packings (HDSPs) related to the error-correcting codes used by cell phones, space probes and the Internet for signal communication through noisy channels? HDSPs strike me as super abstract objects and I'm having a hard time even wrapping my head around their possible concrete applications.

Comment: In what context did sphere packing come up?  Please reference where you've read or heard about it.

Comment: Was reading an article published onQuanta on HDSPs and that's literally the context i.e. it's casually mentioned in a single sentence that HDSps are used thus.

Comment: That's not a reference to an article as references go, @user51309 .

Comment: https://www.quantamagazine.org/sphere-packing-solved-in-higher-dimensions-20160330/?utm_content=buffer15425&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 0):

Does the sphere radius indicate the acceptable deviation away from nominal magnitude and phase? If the total energy (signal + noise + ISI + deterministic trash) moves outside that radius, the energy is interpreted as a different symbol.

Answer (score -1):

The math is way over my head for the [**proof**](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04246.pdf) of \$E_8\$ and \$E_{24}\$ which defines how to arrange spheres to occupy the most space.

*It uses d-dimensional Euclidean space,  Fourier transforms, Schwartz function, holomorphic congruent subgroups,  Eisenstein series, Fourier expansions, Eigenvalues, Modular Forms, Poincare´ series with Bessel Functions.*

- Although some residuals were rounded off, the best computer tests could not find an error of more than \$10^{-28}\$ in \$E_{24}\$ .

Although based on the Leech Lattice, the inspiration for the proof used the \$G_{24}\$ 24 bit [Golay code] used for error correction such that 3 errors could be corrected in 12 bits of data in 24 bit words. [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code)

The symmetry of this lattice model may lead to more beautiful revelations in nature using this with Quantum Theory, *not just how to stack oranges better in the supermarket.*
[image]